# How to have different x-frame-options for different pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have added an X-FRAME-OPTION header to my .htaccess to prevent issues with click jacking.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>
```

Now I am required to allow a certain route to be accessible via an iframe from outside domains. I'm using PHP and have tried overwriting the X-frame-option header via:

```
  header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
```

However it appears that the X-frame-option is not being overwritten but is instead being re-appended as per the following browser error (Chrome):

```
Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('GOFORIT, SAMEORIGIN') encountered when loading 'https://foo.com/baz/1'. Falling back to 'DENY'.
```

How do you go about overwriting the x-frame-options for certain pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap these directives inside of `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>`, like most directives, to limit the URL's they apply to.

Also if you intend to overwrite the header, use 'Header set' instead of 'Header append'.

Answer (score 0):

After some careful deliberation, I ended up moving the header attachment to the application code. In my case I'm using codeigniter so I ended up attaching the x-frame-option header in a hook.

Covener's solution is also a possibility but it appears that you will have to have access to either the apache config file or the virtual host file as both `<location>` and `<locationMatch>` cannot be used within an .htaccess file.